# Почему атрибут skew patternTransform не работает?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern patternTransform='skew(10)' id="a" x='5' y='5' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="15" cx="15" cy="15" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: patternTransform=rotate(20)skewX(30)scale(1 0.5) пишется вторым параметром

Comment: @MaximLensky ошибка была в том что skew(10) надо исправить на skewX(10) или skewY(10)

Comment: да всё правильно просто я показал как их все писать

Comment: @MaximLensky ну не все :))

Comment: а что ещё не так ?

Comment: @MaximLensky знаю еще одно patternTransform=translate(2);

Comment: тоже через Х и Y это же матрица

Comment: @MaximLensky ясно

Comment: ну жди Аlexandr_TT он ещё даже с анимацией сделает - мне лень такое писать я щас больше к js склоняюсь - svg чуть чуть уже не то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автор вопроса уже сам нашёл причину:

> ошибка была в том, что `skew(10)` надо исправить на **skewX(10)** или
> **skewY(10)**

Дополню это решение примерами с немного измененным кодом для симметричного расположения паттерна внутри прямоугольника

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern patternTransform='skewX(10)' id="a" x='5' y='5' width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle r="15" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

### Примеры анимации patternTransform

**skewX**

```
 <animateTransform begin="rect.mouseover" end="rect.mouseleave" 
    attributeName="transform" type="skewX"
    values="0;15;15;-15;-15;0"
    repeatCount="5" dur="2s"/>
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern  id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           
            <circle r="15" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)">
              <animateTransform begin="rect.mouseover" end="rect.mouseleave" attributeName="transform" type="skewX" values="0;15;15;-15;-15;0" repeatCount="5" dur="2s"/> 
            </circle>
         </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
 
</svg>
```

**skewY**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern  id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           
            <circle r="15" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)">
              <animateTransform
                begin="rect.mouseover"
                end="rect.mouseleave"
                attributeName="transform"
                type="skewY"
                values="0;15;15;-15;-15;0"
                repeatCount="5"
                dur="2s"/> 
            </circle>
         </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
 
</svg>
```

**rotate**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern  id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           
            <circle r="15" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)">
              <animateTransform
                begin="rect.mouseover"
                end="rect.mouseleave"
                attributeName="transform"
                type="rotate"
                values="0,20,20;360,20,20"
                repeatCount="5"
                dur="2s"/> 
            </circle>
         </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
 
</svg>
```

**scale**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='b'>
      <stop offset='20%' stop-color='green'></stop>
      <stop offset='40%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
      <stop offset='60%' stop-color='red'></stop>
      <stop offset='80%' stop-color='yellow'></stop>
      <stop offset='100%' stop-color='tomato'></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

        <defs>
          <pattern  id="a" x='0' y='0' width="40" height="40" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           
            <circle r="15" cx="20" cy="20" fill="url(#b)">
              <animateTransform
                begin="rect.mouseover"
                end="rect.mouseleave"
                attributeName="transform"
                type="scale"
                values="1;1.2;1.2;1;1"
                repeatCount="5"
                dur="2s"/> 
            </circle>
         </pattern>
        </defs>

  <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#a)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
 
</svg>
```